# How to read multi url-encoded text by reqparse.parser in python

Tags: python, parsing, flask

I am using python (flask) for reading input from command line using following code but when i pass url-encoded strings(multi arguments seperated with space) as input it gets merged to single sting with space as '+'.

Sample.py

```
from flask_restful import reqparse
parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
parser.add_argument('output')
args = parser.parse_args()
indata=args['output']
print(urllib.parse.quote_plus(indata))
```

run:

```
python sample.py 
curl http://localhost:5000/mypage -d "output=ld%22+to+the+term old+%7B%0A++++pub" -X POST -v
```

output:

```
 ld%22+to+the+term+old+%7B%0A++++pubin
```

while i expect output to be

```
   ld%22+to+the+term  old+%7B%0A++++pubin  (so that they can be spitted easily with separator)
```

How can i avoid such thing?

Comment: why are you using `flask_restful.reqparse` for parsing command line arguments? There are dedicated libraries like [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) for that.

Comment: thansk for your advise. I changed my question but still same pbm even if i use flask_restful.reqparse.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i am reading text(urlencoded) from command line and trying to process them and passing output to webservice.

Comment: why do you need to use `flask_restful.reqparse` in the first place? The whole thing is deprecated: https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.6/reqparse.html

Comment: Why not just use `sys.argv` directly?

Comment: i cannot use sys.argv as i start my webservice at one pplace where i don't pass any parameter while i pass parameter when i use curl. Can you pls advise some alternate as i am new bie in python.

Comment: could you please edit the question to include all the code that you have and exact commands that you are trying to run? so far it's totally unclear what you doing and what is the purpose of your code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181257/discussion-between-manish-and-devstr).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use spaces in form parameters (which you pass with `-d` in curl).

I suggest you urlencode your parameters before passing them to curl or use some other http client that does that for you. 
e.g. [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) or [httpie](https://httpie.org/)

Comment: But request and httpie start from web but i want to pass my input on commnd line only.

Comment: `httpie` installs a command line tool which can be used to send http requests from the command line.